# Not able to download SQL Server image for docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm running docker desktop on Windows and I'm trying to download the SQL Server image using the following command:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/":
> net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
> (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

This is a new install of docker, here are the details:

- Docker Desktop: 4.25.0 (126437)
- Engine: 24.0.6
- Compose: v2.23.0-desktop.1
- Credential Helper: v0.7.0
- Kubernetes: v1.28.2

Things I've tried, other details:

- I can run this command successfully: docker pull nginx
- I am able to run docker hello-world
- I don't have any entries in my host file that reference local host. I also tried removing all entries in my host file, that did not have any effect.
- I am not running a proxy server, I'm not on a vpn, I have the standard windows firewall settings, I have the standard windows anti-virus (not running anything else)

I'm missing something in my setup but I don't know what, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _SQL_ is a _language_, It can't be downloaded. You want MS SQL Server.

Comment: yes, I am aware that sql (structured query language) is itself not an application. I am in fact trying to run a ms-sql docker container. Apologies for not explicitly stating I am trying to run microsoft sql server, I assumed that would be obvious from the docker statement I included in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few potential solutions that may work for you:

- First, try changing your primary/alternate DNS server settings to 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 and then restarting the Docker service.
- Try disabling experimental features.
- Set DNS servers to Automatic.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I added the dns settings to my config and restarted but no luck, I get the same error. Below is what I have in my config:

{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "dns": [
    "8.8.8.8",
    "8.8.4.4"
  ],
  "experimental": false
}

Comment: Did you try changing the connections to your Windows system directly?

Comment: No sure what you mean by that, if you mean the dns settings, I've tried those both ways, with and without them in the config.

Comment: I meant directly editing your Windows config settings, not the Docker config settings.